# Kafka Sliding Window

Tags: apache-kafka, dsl, apache-kafka-streams, sliding-window

I want to implement Kafka streams sliding window and perform an aggregation for the particular window duration and output only one result for each window.

Now, I have literally searched the whole of stack overflow but I am not able to find a code implementation related to sliding window.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide some sample data along with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka itself cannot do that, you have to use either 
KSQL

- KSQL https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/aggregate-streaming-data.html
- Kafka Stream SDK https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-streams-easy-stream-processing-framework-to